# Where to find values-v11 & values-v14 in Android Studio Projects?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I'm developing an app that is compatible with froyo+ devices and I need to set a theme that is only compatible with API11+ devices but, I cannot fix this cause (obviously) because as soon as I set the Holo.Dark theme the editor gives me an error about its compatibility. I know that I need those (only one of them) folder and their style.xml files to fix this issue but Android Studio doesn't generate those folder. I am wondering if I need to create all those folders and styles.xml files to do the trick or if there is a real workaround to this?

The current files tree is this

```
├───res
    │   ├───drawable-hdpi
    │   ├───drawable-mdpi
    │   ├───drawable-xhdpi
    │   ├───drawable-xxhdpi
    │   ├───layout
    │   ├───menu
    │   ├───values
    │   ├───values-w820dp
```

Comment: you can create the folders yourself

Comment: Ok, fine. So I assume Google did delete this function in newer APIs

Comment: what do you mean this function, the use of the folders or creating them when you create a new project?

Comment: To automatically create the files

Comment: It never had a "function" to automatically create those directories. It has always been based upon project and activity templates. Those templates change over time, and vary between the ADT plugin for Eclipse and Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks, not it sounds clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android studio, right click res in your project, then New->Android resource file, and select the resource type: Values, and you can select size, region and others properties at left side.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, I was asking if Android Studio could do it automatically.

Comment: As far as I know, Android Studio won't do itself.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Android Studio.
after I create new folder "values-v11", it doesn't show in Android Studio.
you should open this folder in Explore and add *.xml file to this folder then the *.xml file will show in Android Studio in the "values" folder